# UITableView added data doesn't follow the same layout as the sample data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a `UITableView` for an app that I'm working on, its connected to navigation controllers and other views that allow the user to add animals to the tableview. This is done via another tableViewController that loads the data into the animal table when the user taps done (an unwind segue). It should all be very simple and the sample data that I set up look like this:

[image: sample data tableview]

However after the add data process (done while running the app), the test data looks like:

[image: new data tableview]

I've managed to get around a few layout problems by writing small functions like this one for cell height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100 //Whatever fits your need for that cell
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the table view to display all information with the same layout no matter where the data implemented came from (sample or added within app)?

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ('CatCell' is the table cell, 'Cat' is the name and breed structure):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as! CatCell

        let cat = cats[indexPath.row] as Cat
        cell.cat = cat

        return cell
}
```

The `UITableViewController` is made up of:

[image: storyboard layout]

The tableView is updated like so after the user taps done:

```
@IBAction func doneToMyCats(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let catDetailsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? CatDetailsViewController {

        //add the new cat to the cats array
        if let cat = catDetailsViewController.cat {
            cats.append(cat)

            //update the tableView
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: cats.count-1, inSection: 0)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: You might not be using same datasource or same kind of cell... check this..

Comment: As @vienvu said, would you please post to us your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Edited with more information, sorry for the extremely large screenshots

Comment: So, after you add new object to `cats` collection, how do you udpate the tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try maybe instead of inserting your cell like you wrote use tableView reload data method:

```
@IBAction func doneToMyCats(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
if let catDetailsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? CatDetailsViewController {

    //add the new cat to the cats array
    if let cat = catDetailsViewController.cat {
        cats.append(cat)

        //update the tableView
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}